# Normalize [cassini], [vs-devserver], [web-development-server], etc

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There is a bunch of similar not synonymized tags meaning [Visual Studio Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx) (Codename Cassini):

- [cassini](/questions/tagged/cassini)
- [vs-devserver](/questions/tagged/vs-devserver)
- [web-development-server](/questions/tagged/web-development-server)
- [aspnet-development-server](/questions/tagged/aspnet-development-server)
- [asp.net-development-serv](/questions/tagged/asp.net-development-serv)
- name it?

We need to choose *one* and merge and synonymize the rest.

Comment: [tag:web-development-server] isn't used strictly with Cassini - it's used for all kinds of technologies, and seems useless enough it should maybe be blacklisted.

Comment: The devs haven't blacklisted a tag in over a year.  +1 for synonymizing the rest.